# fs.append into an already existing line with JSON

Tags: javascript, json

The code snippet below is of my JSON file/database that contains the users name and bank balance.

the issue i have ran into is, when the script goes to change the bank balance using "fs.writeFileSync" it over writes the already existing data with the new data. this means i have to make it copy all existing data and paste it in with the new data.

I have also tried using "fs.appendFileSync" but this just adds the new data and doesn't merge any data as expected.

My goal is to have the script navigate into the "Bank" value and merge the new bank value with the old one leaving the "FirstName" and the "LastName" untouched

JSON

```
{
  "User": {
    "user1": {
      "FirstName": "firstname",
      "LastName": "lastname",
      "Bank": 20000
    }
  }
}
```

```
//javascript
let newBalance = 100

let jsonInfo = { 
        User : {
          User : {
            "Bank" : newBalance
          }
        }
    };
     
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(jsonInfo, null, 2);
    fs.writeFileSync('server/userdata.json', jsonData);
```

using this data we got from "newBalance" and "jsonInfo", the new "bank" value in the json file should be "100" and the "FirstName" and "LastName" should still be "firstname" and "lastname"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Because writeFileSync brings data and saves into the path so original data is needed to write on the path. In the json format newBalance can be used like below.

```js
//javascript
let newBalance = 100

let user = {
  "User": {
    "user1": {
      "FirstName": "firstname",
      "LastName": "lastname",
      "Bank": newBalance
    }
  }
}

    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(user, null, 2);
    fs.writeFileSync('server/userdata.json', jsonData);
```